# Car AI Blender Game

Tags: game-engine

How does one go about creating an AI of a Car that can find the shortest route around a track?
[image: Track]
That is my track and the cube is a placeholder for a car.

Any help is appreciated :)

P.S.: I'm a little new to this

**Edit:** I've tried [How to make car AI in my game?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21209/how-to-make-car-ai-in-my-game) , but for some reason it doesn't work on a circuit - only works on point A to B.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work with a loop, cause the car try to find the shortest path to target : so when it reaches it, it just stop.

One solution is to split the circuit in two parts (two Steering actuators*, two navmesh, two targets). When the car reaches the first target, she stops using the first Steering and start using the second one, and try reaching second target.

[image]

At start, a property "part" is set to 1. The first two sensors are then True, so they will activate the first  Steering actuator, and try to reach "first target".

To detect that it reaches a target, you can use an invisible collider : a Static object, with "Ghost" checked (so the player can pass through it), and "Invisible" checked. The object has a unique Game property : ie "first target", "second target". On the car, a Collision sensor with the same property activate a Property sensor and change the value of "part".

When the "part" changes to 2, the first two sensors are now False, but the second couple ("Always.001" and "part 2") are now True ; so the second Steering is activated.

When it reaches the second target, "part" become 1 again, and so on.

In the example, I enabled "Check physics visualization" and showed the property "part" during the game ; so it's easier to understand.

*It will be cleaner to use two States (you can see them as "behaviours"), but you mentioned you where new to that, so I tried to keep it simple.*

*It's probably possible (and easier) to use only one navmesh, and just switch targets*

Comment: It does work, but I want it to move independently because now it's going to target the center of origin of the mesh; instead of finding the shortest way around the track it finds the shortest way to the segment and then sharply adjusts to go to the next segment

Comment: See this: https://i.imgur.com/hFwUaG0.png  The line should be a good curve, but it's got that jittery-ness at the end cause' it's trying to move to the origin of the empty.